# Where does a question about how to put meta data in webpages belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to find out how to best put meta data in webpages, but so far can't find the right site. I've asked variants of it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26473685/3939277), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/260766/153904), and [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/71210/45656). In all transparency, I posted an admittedly overzealous and overly accusatory follow-up [on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242490/274106), but I hope to redeem that by simply asking this.

I asked it on **Stack Overflow** first, because I thought it was ["a specific programming problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it was put on hold as off-topic, citing that ["This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473685/how-many-keywords-is-too-many#comment41584773_26473685). A following comment recommended that I ["Try Webmasters"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473685/how-many-keywords-is-too-many#comment41584806_26473685), so then I posted it to **Webmasters**, and it was marked as a duplicate of an unrelated question. This tells me that Webmasters is likely the ideal place, but it'll need some rewording before it's on-topic. Later, I tried giving it a full rewording and asking on **Software Engineering** because I figured it was a question about ["development methodologies and processes"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It seems that is not the case, since it was also put on hold as off-topic.

**What's the best site to find out how to include meta data in webpages?** If one of the above listed sites is perfect, then **how can I better word my question so that it is both unique and on-topic?**

Comment: Did you try researching for similar questions (not closed, use advanced search options) on those sites to see how they present the issue?

Comment: It is definitely off topic at both [so] (it's not programming (code) or programmers tool related) and [programmers.se] (not programming related at all). It is in fact about SEO, and therefore is most on topic at [webmasters.se]. If it was closed there as a duplicate, edit your question to explain why you feel it's not a duplicate of that question, clarify what you're asking, and see if you can get it reopened. (I can't suggest how you could reword it, as I have no need to be familiar with SEO and have not joined [webmasters.se].)

Comment: Take a glance at [SE Search: web page metadata SEO](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=web+page+metadata+SEO) would help in finding which sites have questions about SEO and meta data (and some possible answers for you).

Comment: Webmasters is probably the correct place.  You should ask for guidance on their meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've correctly surmised Webmasters is probably the best place for your question.

If it was closed as a duplicate of an "unrelated" question, then that's probably an indication that you weren't as clear as you could have been in your question.

Take a few minutes to re-read your question and the putative duplicate. If you can, reword your question to make it clear that it's not a duplicate. This will put the question on the reopen review queue where others can see and vote to reopen if they agree. If it's not salvageable then asking a new question is OK - as long as it's sufficiently different.